# css path relative not taking

Tags: html, css, path

i have css path `/opt/ion/node/service/public` in this path cc.css

i want to move that css to `/opt/ion/node/service/views/pages` but it is not taking

whenever i am hitting the server it is pointing to public so my html is not picking the css file

help me out in changing the file path of  css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cc.css" />
```

as i am using the href so always it is pointing to public

Comment: `public` is your webroot? are you sure you can access to `../views/pages`?

Comment: What about: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cc.css">`. Just tip, I don't  know where you have root, how you rewrite URLs, etc.

Comment: i tried that also but its not taking

Comment: then you can't access to a folder outside the webroot. Try with a symbolic link instead

Comment: yeah i can access it

Comment: You use any type of architecture, we don't know how you are routing, how you create URLs. There is only a few possibilities what URLs can be there, you can try them or return styles to previous location.

Comment: if you tried the @DanielIgnat answer and you didn't solved then you can't make a request to a resource in that folder

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../public/cc.css" />

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../views/pages/cc.css" />
```

Maybe?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../public/cc.css" />